# How to overwrite all the free disk space with 0x00?

Tags: c++, c, windows

how to overwrite all free disk space with zeros, like the *cipher* command in Windows; for example:

```
cipher /wc:\
```

This will overwrite the free disk space in three passes. How can I do this in C or C++? (I want to this in one pass and as fast as possible.)

Comment: Just create a file and write `0` to it until it fails

Comment: @AlanBirtles: this does not work on optimizing file systems that compress file contents on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a set a files and write random bytes to them until available disk space is filled. These files should be removed before exiting the program.

The files must be created on the device you wish to clean.

Multiple files may be required on some file systems, due to file size limitations.

It is important to use different non repeating random sequences in these files to avoid file system compression and deduplicating strategies that may reduce the amount of disk space actually written.

Note also that the OS may have quota systems that will prevent you from filling available disk space and may also show erratic behavior when disk space runs out for other processes.

Removing the files may cause the OS to skip the cache flushing mechanism, causing some blocks to not be written to disk. A `sync()` system call or equivalent might be required. Further synching at the hardware level might be delayed, so waiting for some time before removing the files may be necessary.

Repeating this process with a different random seed improves the odds of hardware recovery through surface analysis with advanced forensic tools. These tools are not perfect, especially when recovery would be a life saver for a lost Bitcoin wallet owner, but may prove effective in other more problematic circumstances.

Using random bytes has a double purpose:

- prevent some file systems from optimizing the blocks and compress or share them instead of writing to the media, thus overwriting existing data.
- increase the difficulty in recovering previously written data with advanced hardware recovery tools, just like these security envelopes that have random patterns printed on the inside to prevent exposing the contents of the letter by simply scanning the envelope over a strong light.

Comment: thank you so much for you good answer, is it required to use random bytes ? if I just overwrite with zeros the data is still recoverable or they are almost gone?

Comment: @sofia: I added some explanations in the answer for this point.

Comment: @Sofia "*data is still recoverable*" If that's the real purpose then you should make that clear in the question. Simply overwriting the free space will not render *all* previous data unrecoverable. For one example, on an NTFS volume small files are stored inside the MFT directly. Deleting such a file just marks the entry as deleted, but does not clear the previous contents and, since that remains owned by the MFT, it's not counted under "*free space*" either.

Comment: @dxiv  thank you so much for details and sorry about that, but most of the files become unrecoverable and that's enough for me